# Proper email sending class asp.net 4.0 IIS 7.5 SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, email, smtp

Does anybody have proper email sending class for asp.net 4.0 c# ?

Currently i have something like below

What suggestions would you make this below class ?

```
public static string sendEmail(string srEmailAddress, string srFrom, string srSubject, string srBodyHTML, string srBodyText)
{
    using (MailMessage Email = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("noreply@monstermmorpg.com", srFrom), new MailAddress(srEmailAddress)))
    {
        Email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        Email.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Email.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Email.Subject = srSubject;

        using (AlternateView textPart = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(srBodyText, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"))
        {
            textPart.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
            Email.AlternateViews.Add(textPart);
        }

        using (AlternateView htmlPart = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(srBodyHTML, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html"))
        {
            htmlPart.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
            Email.AlternateViews.Add(htmlPart);
        }

        try
        {
            using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtpClient.Host = "127.0.0.1";
                smtpClient.Port = 25;
                smtpClient.Send(Email);
                return "True";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            return E.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

c# 4.0 asp.net 4.0 IIS 7.5

Comment: @DJKRAZE it is the whole question. I am asking whether this class is good enough or can be improved ? And yes does anybody gonna fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SmtpClient` is correct. FYI, you can specify the `Host` and `Port` in the constructor, but other than that it's fine.

```
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 25))
{
    smtpClient.Send(Email);
    return true;
}
```

I would change the return type though... either return a `bool` of `true` or `false`, or make the return type `void` and catch the exception in the calling code.

EDIT: To answer your question about catching the exception... Instead of catching an `Exception` inside of your `sendEmail` method (which should be `SendEmail` to follow the C# naming standards, by the way), you should catch the exception from where you call `sendEmail`.

```
try
{
    sendEmail(/*whatever parameters you need */);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Do whatever you need to do with the exception... Display a notification
    // to the user, etc
}
```

Also, you should try not to catch all exceptions - only the ones you are expecting - which in this case is most likely an `SmtpException`.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. but i did not understand the part catch exception in the calling code ? what do you mean by that

Comment: so SmtpException can occur which part of this class do you think ?

Comment: `SmtpClient` can throw a `SmtpException` if the connection to the server failed, authentication failed, etc. Review [this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) which shows what exceptions that method throws.

Comment: Also this function fails at current state because AlternateViews are getting disposed :D i was not using "using" before there

Comment: Then expand your `using` statements for the `AlternateViews` to surround the `using` of the `SmtpClient`.